# How to handle In-App purchases for other countries in iOS app available only in one country?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, review

I have an iOS app which is available only in one country (by changing its availability in App Store Connect).

For other countries or regions, when trying to subscribe I don't get in-app purchases from back end and hence, subscription fails. Then I show a popup with this message: *Failed to initialize In-App in your region*.

Apple rejected our app with this message: *In-App Purchase failed to load successfully*. It has happened twice even after explaining this in App Store Connect Resolution Center.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I definitely might be wrong, but **everything** - IAP, subscriptions, up-front - should be **equal** across where your app is available. Why be (or what is) selective with your app?

Comment: One of the first things your app should do is fetch the available products and check that the user can make purchases. If you get no products or the user is not permitted to make purchases then you should hide the purchase UI. Don't permit the user to attempt a purchase and then return an error.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. It was because of backend bug.